# Remove populated event data in wdCaledar

Tags: javascript, jquery

if anyone is familiar with the jquery plugin wdCalendar:
http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php
 how would i go about removing the automatic populated events so that the calendar will be cleared of all the events data that's there for demo purposes? I want to use the plugin on my website so i'll need it to be clear of the demo events.

Comment: There is a datafeed url in the opts passed to `bcalendar` remove that and try

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?